# How to find the angle of $u$ and $v?$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let S denote the hemisphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ , $z\ge0$, and let $F(x,y,z)=xi+yj$. Let $n$ be the unit outward normal of $S$. Compute the value of the surface integral $\iint_S{F.n} dS$ , using

$a)$ the vector representation $r(u,v)= \sin u \cos v i+ \sin u \sin v j + \cos u k$

I know the answer $\frac {4 \pi}{3}$

But here I don't know how to find the  angle  of $u$ and $v?$

In answer it is given that  $0 \le u \le \pi/2$ and $0 \le v \le 2\pi$ but  i didn't understand how  we got $u \in [0, \pi/2]$ and  $v \in [0, 2\pi]$

Comment: You may look [here](https://mathinsight.org/spherical_coordinates) to understand the spherical coordinates better. Note that $u=\phi$ and $v=\theta$. If you scroll down a bit you'll find an applet to play around with.

Comment: thanks you @A.Γ.